# Sharepoint list - how to identify item ID in view mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Is it possible to find out the ID of the item in the SharePoint List if I open the item in view mode?

For example, I create new item and save to SharePoint list. When I double click on that item I see this item in view form mode. It is possible get ID?

I need this ID for filter Gallery items from second list.

```
Filter(Properties, ID = "Current open item in view mode")
```

Without Filter I will see all items in second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current item ID in list form using this:

```
ThisItem.ID
```

So, try using:

```
Filter(Properties, ID = ThisItem.ID)
```

---

**Update from comments**:

Try using this to get the item ID:

```
SharePointIntegration.SelectedListItemID
```

Comment: If i want to put yout code to Gallery ````Items```` I can type only ````ThisRecord.ID```` and follow this error ````The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: Properties failed: Fetching items failed. Possible invalid string in filter query.````

Comment: ````Filter(Properties, ID = ThisItem.ID)```` ThisItem isnt recognized

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of tree view from left pane where you have added the gallery and for which property you are writing this formula?

Comment: Can you try using `SharePointIntegration.SelectedListItemID` or `SharePointIntegration.Selected.ID` for fetching ID?

Comment: you are god. ````SharePointIntegration.SelectedListItemID```` this works. thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!